# The occurrence of letters in string'' - wrong code and output

Tags: java

```
    package HomePlace;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountLetters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = input.next();
        word = word.toUpperCase();

        int[] letterCount = new int[26];
        for (int count = 0; count < word.length(); count++) {
            char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < letters.length; count2++) {
                char lett = letters[count2];
                if ( (lett >= 'A') & (lett <= 'Z') ) {
                    letterCount[lett - 'A']++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
            System.out.println(count + ": " + letterCount[count - 'A'] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So I got this code.. and the output format that I wanted. but somehow the output counts the number of the letters. For example, If I input ABC the output would be

```
A: 3
B: 3
C: 3
.
.
.
```

and so on. I want the output to count each occurrence of letters. So if I put Abc it would be

```
A: 1
B: 1
C: 1
.
.
.
```

and so on.
Which part of the code did I do wrong here?

Comment: You have written redundant nested loops: you first iterate over the characters in the string and then for each character you're getting letters from the char array.  So you should just remove the outer loop `for (int count = 0; count < word.length(); count++)` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Alex's answer is right, also, try map instead of a lot of this insertion and type conversion
Map<String,Integer> where String is your character of input string and integer is the count of this character

Comment: Oh right, I appreciate you for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you are working with POO language which means u have to work with functions.
If u are just looking for a quick solution then the right code should be something like that :

```
package stck;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountLetters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = input.next();
        word = word.toUpperCase();

        int[] letterCount = new int[26];
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 < letters.length; count2++) {
            char lett = letters[count2];
            if ( (lett >= 'A') && (lett <= 'Z') ) {
                letterCount[lett - 'A']++;
            }
        }
        for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
            System.out.println(count + ": " + letterCount[count - 'A'] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

this loop is useless

```
for (int count = 0; count < word.length(); count++)
```

and be careful when u work with and conditions

```
if ( (lett >= 'A') & (lett <= 'Z') ) {`
```